# onEdit event for Google Spreadsheet not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am a newbie to this, so i assume it is a simple mistake. My goal is to copy the data I have written into a sheet in Spreadsheet "test" into a different Spreadsheet called "destination"

This is my code, but it's simply not working.

```
function onEdit(e) {
   var activeCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(e.range.getRow(), e.range.getColumn());
   var destinationCell = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1f4zXuoqTTJIgZmu-fnErxEpBAizhTNZ25kysrhJHUNk').getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(activeCell.getRow(),activeCell.getColumn());
   destinationCell.setValue(activeCell.getValue());
   }
```

Can someone help me?:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this with an installable trigger:

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
    SpreadsheetApp.openById('ssid').getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(e.range.getA1Notation()).setValue(e.value);
}
```

Comment: You sure that works? Is `onMyEdit` a function I don't know about? I did a rather rushed test of that and it didn't work for me (obviously I updated the Spreadsheet to open that I have access to.

Comment: Did you create the installable trigger?

Comment: Try it now.....